# Dynamically displaying swing components in a transparent JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm dealing with a very specific issue. When I remove all the components of a transparent `JPanel` (background color with 0 alpha) and add new components, the removed elements are still displayed in the `JPanel`. [Here is an example of the behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYpD0.png).

And here is the code to generate it:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    public MyPanel() {
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    }

    public void updateComponents() {
        this.removeAll();
        this.revalidate();

        int n = new Random().nextInt(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            this.add(new JButton("Dummy Button"));
        }
    }
}

public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1280, 720);

        MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();

        JButton btUpdate = new JButton("Update");
        btUpdate.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
            panel.updateComponents();
        });

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(btUpdate, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Swing does not handle transparency well. Having said that *"remove all the components"* try using a `CardLayout` instead. (That's the sum total of time I'd be willing to devote to anything involving transparent containers, so best of luck with it.)

Comment: 1) Don't use updateUI(). That is used internally by Swing when the LAF changes. 2) The component appear because the background is not cleared before the new components are painted.  Try invoking revalidate on the frame. 3) Check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information why transparency causes a problem and a solution

Comment: @camickr thank you for the insights, but unfortunately nothing worked out. I have even tried using the `AlphaContainer` described in the link you sent, but still nothing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.revalidate();
```

The point of invoking `revalidate()` is to invoke the layout manager.

You need to invoke that method AFTER you add all the components to the panel.

You also need to make sure the components are painted so the code should be:

```
this.revalidate();
this.repaint();
```

> I have even tried using the AlphaContainer

How? Post your code showing what you attempted.

The usage should be:

```
//frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
frame.getContentPane().add(new AlphaContainer(panel), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: Now it worked out! Using the combination of `Alpha Container`, `revalidate()` and `repaint()`, in the proper order, resulted in the desired behavior.